# ОФФЛАЙН-консультант для сайта на джумле

Tags: html, jquery, css, joomla, chat

Ребят , такой вопрос: нужно сделать выпадающий "чат", но чтоб задаваемый вопрос отправлялся на почту. а не в онлайн режиме. Подскажите , есть ли такие плагины?

Comment: В смысле, на почту, оффлайн... Почтой России что ли?

Comment: @D-side You made my day! Lol

Comment: @D-side, ))))))))))).....

Comment: человек пишет сообщение в этот чат , и оно автоматом на e-mail

Comment: Уф, я уж было испугался. Отредактируйте вопрос, проясните этот момент.

Comment: CTACO23, на [**SIteHeart**](https://www.siteheart.com/), пожалуйста, [**обратите внимание**](https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/siteheart-fs/). Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно, сервисы, которые предлагают возможность установки на свой сайт онлайн-консультанта по такому же принципу и поступают, то есть:

> задаваемый вопрос отправляется на почту

если нет операторов в онлайне.

Comment: Попробуйте http://www.siteheart.com или http://www.tawk.to